# executing Nunit tests

Tags: c#, nunit

So basically I have my cs file, which uses Nunit.Testing, under the same project. When I go to "TEST>Execute>All Tests" it doesn't find any.

Where should I specify that this file is to be used for the tests?
Thank you

I am using VS Express for Web 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, releases of Visual Studio prior to VS 11 did not have the ability to directly run tests built with Open Source testing frameworks like NUnit.

Basically, in order to run your NUnit tests, you can use the NUnit test runner GUI tool (look inside your NUnit install folder to find the nunit.exe file).

If you use VS 11 or later and want integrated test execution you can take a look at [NUnit Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d) plugin.
Resharper can also run NUnit tests directly from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run VS Express for Web 2013 then I'd suggest you get a copy of [Visual Studio Community 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com), it's basically a free version of Visual Studio Pro 2013 and you can use NUnit with it no problems.

It also gives you a lot more than the Express editions.